# PostgreSQL driver to run SQL per connection

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

Is there a PostgreSQL JDBC driver which supports `connectionInitSql` and can be used with hikari?

I've looked at the following:

https://jdbc.postgresql.org/
https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc

But neither of them support it.

Code:

```
HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
config.setDataSourceClassName("org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource");
config.addDataSourceProperty("connectionInitSql", "SET ROLE admin");
HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource(config)
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Property connectionInitSql does not exist on target class org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.PropertyElf.setProperty(PropertyElf.java:131)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.PropertyElf.lambda$setTargetFromProperties$0(PropertyElf.java:57)
at java.util.Hashtable.forEach(Hashtable.java:878)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.PropertyElf.setTargetFromProperties(PropertyElf.java:52)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.initializeDataSource(PoolBase.java:331)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.<init>(PoolBase.java:109)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:108)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:81)
```

Comment: That property is a feature of Hikari, and will work with any JDBC driver. If you're not using Hikari, then you need to create the equivalent yourself. If you are using Hikari and it doesn't work, then post the code/config and describe how it fails.

Comment: Huh? The error is 'not supported by this driver', because the driver doesn't support it. I'm looking for a driver which does

Comment: I repeat: If you are using Hikari and it doesn't work, then post the code/config and describe how it fails. Post the full exception stack trace.

Comment: I will post it if you really want, but it is a waste if time. On the hikari docs, `connectionInitSql` is optional, and not supported by the drivers that I listed. I'm looking for a postgres driver that supports it

Comment: I'm 100% sure this does not require driver-specific support. I maintain a JDBC driver myself, and this function from Hikari works without ever having implemented anything for it in the driver itself. You are either looking at the wrong message from the logs, or you have configured it incorrectly.

Comment: In fact, I have now also tested it against PostgreSQL and it works.

Comment: As Mark said, this is a Hikari option, not a JDBC option. If it says "not supported by this driver", that means you're trying to set the property on the JDBC driver, rather than on the [`HikariConfig`](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/603951febd167ce086c2a65ace1668cf8488db5e/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariConfig.java#L374).

Comment: OK, thanks - I'm updating the question with my code/error

Comment: I up voted all of your comments... 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out my issue. The `connectionInitSql` is set using

```
config.setConnectionInitSql()
```